# PHP PDO Transactions SQL Server 2014 Error

Tags: php, pdo, transactions, sql-server-2014

I'm struggling with PDO Transactions and SQL Server to save some invoices details:

System is based on Windows Server 2012 R2, SQL Server 2014 and php 7.14

The problem is that although both queries are executed and I find the records in the database (therefore I suppose that both $DB and SQL Queries are OK)

I also installed the latest drivers (5.2): php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts_x64.dll

I always receive the following response:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: There is no active transaction in line 191

where line 191 contains `$DB->commit();`

I tried these 3 solutions:

```
try
{
    $DB->beginTransaction();
    $IB=$DB->prepare($SQLBody);
    $IH=$DB->prepare($SQLHeader);
    $IB->execute();
    $IH->execute();
    $DB->commit();
}
catch(PDOExecption $e)
{
    $DB->rollback();
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>";
}
```

then I tried this:

```
try
{
    $DB->beginTransaction();
    $DB->query($SQLBody);
    $DB->query($SQLHeader);
    $DB->commit();
}
catch(PDOExecption $e)
{
    $DB->rollback();
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>";
}
```

and finally this as found [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/pdo-begintransaction?view=sql-server-2017) (that works although seems for sql server 2017)

```
try
{
    $DB->beginTransaction();
    $IB=$DB->exec($SQLBody);
    $IH=$DB->exec($SQLHeader);
    $DB->commit();
}
catch(PDOExecption $e)
{
    $DB->rollback();
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>";
}
```

can suggest what's wrong?

Comment: Perhaps autocommit is enabled? Try calling `$DB->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, false);` before `beginTransaction()`.

Comment: tried but seems ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT is not available for sql server